# Armature Single Bone: Extruded Child Bone not Follow Parent

Tags: bones, parent, extrude

I follow a tutorial for the creation of armature.

Steps:

1. Add single bone ("main bone").
2. Go to Edit mode.
3. Extrude from tip ("tip bone").
4. Extrude from root ("root bone").
5. Go to Pose mode. Move "main bone."

When I move "main bone," the "tip bone" follows the main bone. The "root bone" stays in place and does not follow the "main bone."

In Scene Collection pane, there is information that indicates that the "tip bone" is parented to the "main bone." This information indicates that the "root bone" is not parented to the "main bone."

I parent "root bone" to "main bone" so it follows "main bone."

The tutorial I follow indicates that I don't have to do this, manually.

Is there a way to extrude bones from the first single bone in scene so that extruded bones are automatically children of the "main bone," so they follows the "main bone" as expected?

Summary:
Bones extruded from "tip" of bone follows bone in pose mode.
Bones extruded from "root" of bone does not follow bone in pose mode.

Comment: This is how it is supposed to work, if you extrude bone Tip from the tail of bone Main, bone Tup will automatically be a child, if you extrude bone Root from the head of bone Main, bone Root won't be a child, you need to parent it afterwards

Comment: As @moonboots said, this is how it is supposed to work. Since you followed a tutorial, is it working differently there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it is supposed to work, if you extrude bone *Tip* from the tail of bone *Main*, bone *Tip* will automatically be a child, if you extrude bone *Root* from the head of bone *Main*, bone *Root* won't be a child, you need to parent it afterwards